# boto3 how to create object with metadata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

In the example below I want to set a timestamp metadata attribute when created an S3 object.  How do I do that?  The documentation is not clear.

```
import uuuid
import json
import boto3
import botocore
import time

from boto3.session import Session
session = Session(aws_access_key_id='XXX',
                  aws_secret_access_key='XXX')

s3 = session.resource('s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket('blah')

for filename in glob.glob('json/*.json'):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read().decode('utf-8')
        timestamp = str(round(time.time(),10))
        my_s3obj = s3.Object('blah', str(uuid.uuid4())).put(Body=json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 19):

As for boto3, You have the `upload_file()` option detailed in the boto3 website [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/upload_file.html#).

```py
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'hello.txt')
```

While uploading a file, you have to specify the key (which is basically your object/file name). Adding the metadata when creating the key would be done using the "**ExtraArgs**" option:

```py
s3ressource.upload_file(
    Filename, bucketname, key, 
    ExtraArgs={
        "Metadata": {
            "metadata1": "ImageName",
            "metadata2": "ImagePROPERTIES",
            "metadata3": "ImageCREATIONDATE"
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Great answer- one minor addition: If you want to modify one of the defined Object metadata keys (Content-Encoding, Content-Type, etc.) you must use them directly in `ExtraArgs` (i.e. `ExtraArgs={"ContentEncoding": "gzip"}`)

Comment: Yes, it depends on the server... AWS has 2KB while onpremises system can have more. http://docs.netapp.com/sgws-112/topic/com.netapp.doc.sg-s3/GUID-0BEF8D16-B743-4BF6-8E27-A5FE4D33C1F0.html

Comment: @Tommy, Surround your code with 

3 backticks python
CODE
3 backticks

No space between the top 3 backticks and the language name like python in this case.

Answer (score 10):

You can specify metadata for the object as key-value pairs like this:

```
s3.Object('bucket-name', 'uuid-key-name').put(Body='data', 
                                              Metadata={'key-name':'value'})
```

See the [boto3 docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put) for other parameters you can use inside `put()`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import boto3

def convert_key_values_to_string(data):
    """
    Converts the keys and values of a dictionary to strings.

    Args:
        data (dict): The dictionary containing key-value pairs.

    Returns:
        dict: A new dictionary with keys and values as strings.
    """
    return {str(key): str(value) for key, value in data.items()}

def save_to_s3(data, metadata, bucket_name, file_key):
    """
    Saves data to an Amazon S3 bucket with specified metadata.

    Args:
        data (bytes): The data to be saved.
        metadata (dict): Metadata associated with the S3 object.
        bucket_name (str): The name of the S3 bucket.
        file_key (str): The key (path) under which to store the data in the bucket.

    Raises:
        Exception: If an error occurs while saving the data to S3.

    Note:
        The 'metadata' dictionary is converted to strings using the
        'convert_key_values_to_string' function as 'Metadata' in S3
        accepts dictionary items with both keys and values as strings only.
    """
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        s3.put_object(
            Body=data,
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            Key=file_key,
            Metadata=convert_key_values_to_string(metadata)
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error saving {file_key}: {e}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).