# Storing matplotlib images in S3 with S3.Object().put() on boto3 1.5.36

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, amazon-s3, io, boto3

Amongst other things I am drawing plots using `matplotlib`, which I would like to immediately store as S3 objects.

According to the answers provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33771318/1129682) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40336918/1129682) question and the [fine manual](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object), I need `S3.Object.put()` to move my data into AWS and the procedure should be along the lines of

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import boto3
import io

# plot something
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, 500)
a = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x**2))

# get image data, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45099838/1129682
buf = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buf, format="png")
buf.seek(0)
image = buf.read()

# put the image into S3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=awskey, aws_secret_access_key=awssecret)
s3.Object(mybucket, mykey).put(ACL='public-read', Body=image)
```

However, I end up with a new S3 object with content-length zero.

The following gives me a new S3 object with content-length 6.

```
s3.Object(mybucket, mykey).put(ACL='public-read', Body="foobar")
```

When I put the next line, I end up with content in the S3 object, but its not a usable image:

```
s3.Object(mybucket, mykey).put(ACL='public-read', Body=str(image))
```

I can make it work by going through an actual file, like this:

```
with open("/tmp/iamstupid","wb") as fh:
    fig.savefile(fh, format="png")
s3.Bucket(mybucket).upload_file("/tmp/iamstupid", mykey)
```

So it seems to work. I am just unable to use the interface correctly. What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve my goal using `S3.Object.put()`

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve it. I found the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8908287/1129682). Its a Python3 thing. From what I understand Python3 "usually" works with unicode. If you want single bytes you have to be explicit about it. The correct usage therefore is

```
s3.Object(mybucket, mykey).put(ACL='public-read', Body=bytes(image))
```

I find this a bit strange, since `buf.read()` is already supposed to return an object of type `bytes` but I did stop wondering, b/c it works now.